# XTS - to use yesterday value as input for today

Tags: r, xts

I have a XTS object wgt

`head(wgt)` shows

```
Date                      A            B           
2001-01-01               50           50   
2001-02-28               50           50
2001-03-31               50           50
```

Bascially `wgt[T] = wgt[T-1] * Random operation`

I tried with `lag.xts` but it didn't deliever the result

I do want to update the elements `wgt$A` for Date 2001-02-28 based on the value from 2001-01-01 element  ie the result would be 90 = 50+40
In the next step the result for this element will be input for the calculation carried out on 2001-03-31  ie 70 =90-20

Thanks for your support

martin

Answer (score 0):

If `head(wget)` shows a "Date" column, then your object is not an xts object. xts objects do not have a date-time column.

What you're describing is a recursive operation, and that is easily performed using a simple for loop.

```
# sample data
wget <- read.csv(text="Date,A,B
2001-01-01,50,50
2001-02-28,50,50
2001-03-31,50,50", as.is=TRUE)
# convert to xts
wget_xts <- xts(wget[,-1], as.Date(wget[,1]))
# loop over wget_xts and apply random operation
set.seed(21)
for (i in 2:nrow(wget_xts)) {
  wget_xts[i, "A"] <- wget_xts[i-1, "A"] + sample(-20:40, 1)
}
```